# How do I perform operations on ObjectId as a part of query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a numeric id that I want to export and process.

I have a Python script that receives a JSON document and transforms it, so I can run a Unix pipe that starts with `mongoexport` and pipes its output into Python like this:

```
mongoexport --host myhost --db mydb --collection mycol  | python ./transform.py
```

However this operation is very long (everything is processed in one thread) so I found a way to parallelize it. I split my (numeric) id into 8 chunks (by using `id mod 8`) and run 8 processes in parallel like this:

```
for var in {0..7} 
do
    mongoexport --host myhost --db mydb --collection mycol --query '{ id: { $mod: [8, '$var']} }' | python ./transform.py &
done
```

This separates my collection into 8 non-intersecting fractions that together cover all of my collection.

Another collection I have has a default ObjectId, and I want to do the following:

```
for var in {0..7} 
do
    mongoexport --host myhost --db mydb --collection mycol --query '{ _id: { $mod: [8, '$var']} }' | python ./transform.py &
done
```

However, in this case the ObjectId does not support modulo operation.

How can I separate my collection into non-intersecting fractions by using ObjectId?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Python to drive your script, instead of bash. An ObjectId's [first four bytes are the time it was created](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/). So try querying the first and last `_id` in your collection and dividing into eight ranges of equal duration. In Python:

```
min_id = db.collection.find().sort([('_id', 1)]).limit(1)[0]['_id']
start = min_id.generation_time
print start
max_id = db.collection.find().sort([('_id', -1)]).limit(1)[0]['_id']
print max_id.generation_time
delta = max_id.generation_time - min_id.generation_time
step = delta / 8
print step
```

Then, start a thread for each range:

```
import threading, functools

threads = []
for i in range(8):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=functools.partial(my_function, start))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    start += step

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

In `my_function` you should query for all _ids >= start and < start + step:

```
collection.find({'_id': {'$gte': start, '$lt': start + step}})
```